# TypeError Cannot read property 'cwd' of undefined on a TypeScript, NextJS project

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babeljs, next.js

I have seen this error a lot on the web but not so much in the case that interests me.

I am getting the following error whenever I run `yarn dev` :

```
next-dev.js?53bc:89 Error was not caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cwd' of undefined
    at Module.eval (parsers.js?f09d:27)
    at eval (parsers.js:252)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/parsers.js (_app.js?ts=1619702971940:3455)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:873)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:151)
    at eval (backend.js?5e1f:1)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/backend.js (_app.js?ts=1619702971940:3299)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:873)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:151)
    at eval (index.js?54d7:1)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/index.js (_app.js?ts=1619702971940:3335)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:873)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:151)
    at Module.eval (_app.tsx:16)
    at eval (_app.tsx?8548:93)
    at Module../src/pages/_app.tsx (_app.js?ts=1619702971940:11957)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:873)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1619702971940:151)
    at eval (next-client-pages-loader.js?7ae7:5)
    at eval (route-loader.ts?8a46:294)
    enter code here
```

This error happens whether I'm in development mode or production.
I am on a `nextjs` project using `typescript`, `jest` and `babel`.

Apparently it is supposed to be a babel compatibility issue, but in my case all the package are up to date and should work together:

**package.json**

```
"@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "5.9.5",
"@babel/core": "7.13.1",
"@types/jest": "26.0.23",
"babel-jest": "26.6.3",
"jest": "26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "26.5.5",
```

I am wondering what is going on, all the solutions pointed at package compatibility issues, none of which seem to bear fruits in my case...
If you need more info, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody searchhing for the answer, it was actually a `tsconfig` error:

```
{
    // some config goes here
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"],
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
}
```

removing the line `"*": ["node_modules/*"],`is what did the trick.